# Set SimpleAdapter in fragment for ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, adapter

i have successfully implemnted a listview based on a Simpleadapter. Now i wanted to split my application into three tabs. But if i want to set the simpleadapter on my fragment the listview shows nothing and i get no error.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this.getContext(), contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"listTitle", "tonart"}, new int[]{R.id.id,
                R.id.tonart});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i used the same code as in the working app.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use getContext() instead of MainActivity.this

```
     adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            getContext(), contactList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"listTitle", "tonart"}, new int[]{R.id.id,
            R.id.tonart});
```

Comment: the problem is that i get no error. And the json data is in the adapter.

Comment: if this is fragment try with getActivity() instead getContext()

Comment: Check this ...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668368/simple-listview-in-fragment-using-simpleadapter

Answer (score 0):

try to use `getActivity()` instead of `this.getContext()`

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            getActivity(), contactList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"listTitle", "tonart"}, new int[]{R.id.id,
            R.id.tonart});
```