# Simple ListAdapter in fragment using SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

My code for FragmentPhysics.java

```
public class FragmentPhysics extends Fragment{

private ListView lvPhy, lvPhyDownloaded;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> phyList, phyListDownloaded;

public FragmentPhysics() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Activity activity = getActivity();
    Intent intent= activity.getIntent();
    phyList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("phyList");
    phyListDownloaded = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("phyListDownloaded");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_physics, container, false);
    lvPhy = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    lvPhyDownloaded = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);


    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(activity, phyList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "subject","date", "chapter", "info", "idfile", "downloadlink"},
            new int[]{R.id.subject, R.id.date, R.id.chapter, R.id.info, R.id.idfile, R.id.downloadlink});

    ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(activity, phyListDownloaded,
            R.layout.list_item_downloaded, new String[]{ "subject","date", "chapter", "info", "idfile", "downloadlink"},
            new int[]{R.id.subject, R.id.date, R.id.chapter, R.id.info, R.id.idfile, R.id.downloadlink});
    lvPhy.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvPhyDownloaded.setAdapter(adapter2);

    return view;
}
```

My code for fragment_physics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/phy_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@android:id/text1">
            </ListView>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@android:id/text2">
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

In case you need my MainActivity Code,

```
getIntent().putExtra("phyList", phyList);
        getIntent().putExtra("phyListDownloaded", phyListDownloaded);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentPhysics fragmentPhysics = new FragmentPhysics();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.phy_layout, fragmentPhysics).commit();
```

As such there is no error in the code, but when i run the code, the activity just breaks.
Looked into many Stackoverflow questions, even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668368/simple-listview-in-fragment-using-simpleadapter), which is pretty much same as mine, but that doesn't solve my problem.
if i just comment out the`lvPhy.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvPhyDownloaded.setAdapter(adapter2);`, everything works just fine, but a blank screen(as expected). Somebody please help. I am new to android and this is my first question in Stackoverflow.

the errors i am getting is

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.pariksit.insightacademy, PID: 3780
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:100)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:491)
                                                                           at com.pariksit.insightacademy.FragmentPhysics.onCreateView(FragmentPhysics.java:57)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                                                                           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2127)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1243)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1479)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                        at android.view.Chore
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-error-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303544/how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-error-in-android)

Comment: in which list does this exception/error occur

Comment: `phyList`  or `phyListDownloaded` is null.

Comment: verified, they are not null

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the list you are passing to `SimpleAdapter` is null. When you are trying to get the list from `extras` it is `null` which is causing this error.